# How to build a dendrogram-like UI in Vaadin?

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js, svg, vaadin7

It goes as follows: I need to buid a Ui that is something like a dendrogram graph:
https://qx2jwa.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y3mi9PoIFhsHL5qjc_wTPbEL8MK-GY90L2nkb4c3895qov-bljI0jt3Ei2LPJ0-TnC1iVj96GfT1wMy5AsY2DoaJCeSqrYE2GRmO5k7FluY1bT3EbEV_oVdQlsdnq8SHQoWNQTx5UeswbeoEp5TFHTEZyri_VG7MfuIjZ66zK8_Lcc/dendro1.jpg
The nodes or the leaves in the dendrogram represent entities of 3 main types (preferably a different Icon for each type), they should be clickable and respond with a dialog window that the user then can manipulate (to get to the next node/leaf), say containing a table and a few buttons. The user can extend the dendrogram infinitely or start a new ones at any point in the same window.

Does this make sense, could it be built, the dendrogram part in particular? I discovered a very neat piece of code that draws the image above using the D3 library and json (it's an svg). Is it a good idea to to try and use this to build the UI? How to get Vaadin to handle the clicks onto the different nodes in the svg.

I am new to this, hence the many questions, sry ...
Well, thats it more or less...
Thank You!

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with vaadin, there are [some](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) [examples](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092) of how to go about handling click events in tree diagrams. Although they're more simple than what you describe, they should help you to make a start on handling events with d3 and/or javascript. Vaadin might have a way to catch those events with a listener.

Comment: thanks, I've been looking into it.